# How to load dataset for in Keras using Python?

Tags: python, keras, mnist, image-classification

I'm a beginner to learn Keras using Python.

I've read some sample code of dataset loading using MNIST Dataset.

I don't understand the variable (`X_train`, `y_train`) and (`X_test`, `y_test`).

Please, help me explaining the purpose of these variables.

Also, what type of data are assigned to these variables?

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.utils import np_utils

# Load data
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Mnist` Dataset contains about 75 000 sample images of Handwritten Digits. Each Digit also carries a label which contains the digit which can be seen in the image. Each Image has the size `28x28` pixels. These Images are getting split into two sections. The `training-Images` and the `Test-Images`. You use the `training-images` to train your Model. And then you validate your `accuracy` and `loss` by testing how good the resulting neuronal network is working on the till then unused and unseen `test-images`.

`(X_train, Y_train)` is a tuple, a combination of two values stored in one variable/list-element...

The Images then are stored in these Lists as arrays. So `X_train` contains about 60 000 arrays of the size of 784 (28*28). Each cell represents the value of one pixel. It can be anything from 0 (white) to 255 (black)

`X_test` contains a list with about 15 000 such arrays. The Labels fitting the images are stored in the belonging Y_train/Y_test

Answer (score 0):

According to the [keras documentation](https://keras.io/datasets/#mnist-database-of-handwritten-digits):

> x_train, x_test: uint8 array of grayscale image data with shape (num_samples, 28, 28).
>
> y_train, y_test: uint8 array of digit labels (integers in range 0-9) with shape (num_samples,).

`x_train` and `y_train` are features and labels for training, respectively. `x_test` and `y_test` are features and labels for testing, respectively.